# MQTT-PHP Subscribe Stuck in Loop

Tags: php, xampp, mqtt

I'm new to MQTT and I have a problem that this code must run on command line otherwise it stuck in the loop and I need it to run in the background once xampp server starts

```
$mqtt = new \PhpMqtt\Client\MQTTClient($server, $port, $clientId);
$connectionSettings = new \PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings();
$mqtt->connect("user", "pass", $connectionSettings, true);


$mqtt->subscribe('switches/#', function ($topic, $message) {
 
    //echo "here";
    //echo "$d\n";
  $fp = fopen('brlogs.txt', 'a');//opens file in append mode  
fwrite($fp, "$d\n");  
 
fclose($fp);  

}, 0);
$mqtt->loop(true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck in a loop"? Do you want it to exit after the first message is received?

Answer (score 0):

The `$mqtt->loop(true)` call will always block until interrupted by `$mqtt->interrupt()`

See the [docs](https://github.com/php-mqtt/client#subscribe)

If you want this to run in the background you will need run it on it's own thread, I suggest you look at the Thread [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php)